# Can the JVM perform adaptive optimizations on JIT-compiled code if the optimization is really simple with no deoptimization

Tags: java, optimization, jvm

I am still working on high-performance pirated Minecraft. I don't know if the JVM can perform adaptive optimizations on JIT-compiled code if the optimization is really simple with no optimization. I had a concern that deoptimization will cause a lot of lags due to the large methods and the Advanced-Technology Whole-Program Optimization.

Comment: Please clearly express what are you doing and what issue you face. Show the code if you have some and demonstrate the problem with some evidence (logs, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM goes through different levels of optimisations if you are running in tiered mode, combining what was the client and server JITs. If you disable tiering and just stick with the server tier then you will get less deopt situations occurring.

However the deopt compiles can come from a number of reasons, like the first time an exception is thrown out when a new subclass is seen at a dynamic dispatch call site. The reason deopts occur is because the JIT code made some assumptions and those assumptions have been violated.

To totally avoid deopts you will need to execute your code such that it follows all e paths you are likely to experience at runtime prior to them getting hot. In practice this may be near impossible. You would have to punt your objects through the pipeline and throw all the exceptions you are ever likely to see to prime the JIT.

If you want high performance you are probably better advised to try and reduce the amount of garbage produced by your program since that is the most common form of delays.

Most high performance Java servers work by having a warm up set of transactions that can be applied at start up to pre warm the JIT and reduce garbage production as much  as possible.